# getInitialState() is showing error in console

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create toggle menu for my react app.

I am facing some issue with '`getInitialState()`'. It's show error like:

> Warning: getInitialState was defined on Header, a plain JavaScript
>   class. This is only supported for classes created using
>   React.createClass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?*

Here is my code:

```
class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  getInitialState(){
    return {"showHideSidenav":"hidden"};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <div className="toggle-btn" onClick={this.toggleSidenav.bind(this)}>
          <div>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </div>
          <span>Menu</span>
        </div>
        <div className={this.props.showHideSidenav} id="main-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>
               1
            </li>
            <li>
               2
            </li>
            <li>
               3
            </li>
            <li>
              4
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
  toggleSidenav() {
    var css = (this.props.showHideSidenav === "hidden") ? "show" : "hidden";
    this.setState({"showHideSidenav":css});
  }
}
```

How I can I solve this?

Comment: Yes, I have already imported

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between using constructor vs getInitialState in React / React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668326/what-is-the-difference-between-using-constructor-vs-getinitialstate-in-react-r)

Comment: Read this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#setting-the-initial-state

Comment: Try calling 
onClick={this.toggleSidenav.bind(this)}
as
onClick={(e)=> this.toggleSidenav(e)}

Comment: Seems this is a duplicated question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720620/react-es6-getinitialstate-was-defined-on-a-plain-javascript-class
Have you refer this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can find an answer here -> [React, ES6 - getInitialState was defined on a plain JavaScript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720620/react-es6-getinitialstate-was-defined-on-a-plain-javascript-class)

As a summary:

If you use es6 class which extends `React.Component` you need to define the state in the constructor:

```
this.state = {...}
```

`getInitialState()` is used in the es5 `React.createClass` function.